# SQL query for the following db

Tags: sql

```
salesperson:(sid, name, age, salary)
customer :(cid, cname, city)
order:(oid, order_date, cid, sid, amount)
```

SQL query for "Find the names of a salesperson who have two or more orders"

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: out 15 queries this was the only query i was having doubt with. I know this is not the correct place for these questions but cant help as i needed a respected source to check my answers as I have exam tomorrow

Comment: i am using oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Well TESTED**

```
SELECT sp.NAME 
FROM   salesperson AS sp 
       INNER JOIN order AS ord 
               ON salesperson.sid = ord.sid 
GROUP  BY sp.sid 
HAVING Count(ord.oid) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.name, count(o.oid) FROM salesperson s, order o
WHERE s.sid=o.sid
GROUP BY s.name
HAVING count(o.oid)>=2
```

---

Here we are using an `"Inner Join"`, where only the rows where there is correspondence
(`where s.sid=o.sid`) are extracted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.name, count(*) order_count
FROM salesperson AS s, order AS o
WHERE s.sid = o.sid
GROUP BY s.name 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will return the name as well as the count of orders associated with each salesperson